# Have a field display as yyyy/mm/dd based on a text field

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Using PHP and MySQL, I have a table of events that are sorted by a field called: sort_date, formatted in yyyy/mm/dd.

I need the display on the page to show a start_date of: Month dd (November 7, for example).

So I had the start_date and end_date fields originally set as a datepicker. But once a record was entered, I had to go in and change the dates manually to be formatted: Month dd. But that didn't sort the dates in ascending order, so I have a Sort_date field...and this is in yyyy/mm/dd format.

I want the event listed like this on my page:

August 27
Time
Where
Address
Description

This is working, but now that I changed the start and end dates to Text, the sort_date field isn't reading the info.

So my question is, How can I have the sort_date field read what is in the TEXT start_date field and show it as yyyy/mm/dd?

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM events
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
   AND authorize = 1 
 ORDER BY sort_date
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at using moment.ms?

Comment: I see what you are saying, John about STR_TO_DATE()...but how do I have that field read the text entry from another field?

Comment: Here is my sql statement:
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND authorize = 1
ORDER BY sort_date

Answer (score 1):

This takes two steps.

First you need to get your text-column date converted to a `DATE` expression.

You can do that with, for example,

```
 STR_TO_DATE('2014/11/18', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Then, you can manipulate that `DATE` expression, to sort it, or format it, or whatever you need to do. To get `November 2014` from the above expression you'd do:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2014/11/18', '%Y/%m/%d'), '%M %Y')
```

To get a `DATE` value containing the first of November (the first day of the month) from that expression you can do this.

```
DATE(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2014/11/18', '%Y/%m/%d'), '%Y-%m-01'))
```

The point is that you should convert your string-based dates to `DATE` expressions, because then all kinds of useful date arithmetic operations available.

To handle the `WHERE` clause in your question, you do this:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(sort_date, '%Y/%m/%d') >= NOW()
```

To handle the `ORDER BY` clause you could do something like this:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(sort_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

There's a hazard here. If some of your date strings are misformatted, MySQL date conversion will silently return NULL. So, I would use the following `ORDER BY` clause and then look at the output carefully, at least once

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(sort_date, '%Y/%m/%d') NULLS FIRST
```